# Archive multiple log files in a singe archive

Tags: java, log4j2

Is it possible to archive multiple log files into one archive using the log4j2 framework?

eg.

```
--logs
   -ROOT.log
   -ERRORS.log
   -TELEGRAMS.log

   --archive
    --2017_06_23
     -2017_06_23_09_10.log.gz
      -ROOT.log
      -ERRORS.log
      -TELEGRAMS.log
     - ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.**

It is not possible to archive multiple log files into one archived file by Log4j2.